# Contact for name text fields

Tags: wordpress

I use Contact Form 7 plugin in order to add a form to my site.

I use the following "code" in order to add field for name and surname:

```
<label> Name (required)
    [text* name] </label>

<label> Surname (required)
    [text* surname] </label>
```

However I receive this error:

```
Unavailable names (name) are used for form controls
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the name "name" for your fields. Try to prefix it.

```
<label> Name (required)
    [text* my-name] </label>

<label> Surname (required)
    [text* my-surname] </label>
```